# Is there any way to do permutation of more than 11 components?

Tags: matlab, permutation

I am trying to generate all the sequences of a given variable with some precedence constraint. For example, if we have five objects, `[1 2 3 4 5]`, then there are `5! = 125` ways to permute those. However, if we impose some precedence constraints like:

- a) The sequence should always start from 1.
- b) After 1 only 2 or 3 can be attached.
- c) 4 can come after 5 or 3
- d) 5 can come after 4 or 2

only these possibilities remain:

```
1 2 3 5 4, 
1 2 3 4 5,  
1 2 5 4 3, 
1 2 5 3 4,
1 3 4 5 2,
1 3 4 2 5,
1 3 2 5 4,
1 3 2 4 5,
```

Like for six Objects the codes with constraints is:-

```
allCombs = perms(1:objects);
constraintsFor1 = union(findKAfterNRows(allCombs,2,1),findKAfterNRows(allCombs,3,1));
constraintsFor1 = intersect(constraintsFor1,find(allCombs(:,1)==1));
constraintsFor4 = union(findKAfterNRows( allCombs, 4,5 ),findKAfterNRows( allCombs, 4,3 ));
constraintsFor5 = union(findKAfterNRows( allCombs, 5,2 ),findKAfterNRows( allCombs, 5,4 ));
constraintsFor6 = union(findKAfterNRows( allCombs, 6,4 ),findKAfterNRows( allCombs, 6,5 ));
resultRows = intersect(constraintsFor1,constraintsFor4);
resultRows = intersect(resultRows,constraintsFor5);
resultRows = intersect(resultRows,constraintsFor6);
output = allCombs(resultRows,:);
```

Comment: Take a look at [`perms`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html). All you'll have to do then is selecting only one starting with `1` (or even faster: do the `perms` on the array without `1` and prepend that)

Comment: @Adriaan but perms will not allow more then 11 numbers i think.

Comment: What MATLAB version are you using? `A = perms(1:13)` runs fine on R2015a on a 64bit Windows 7 machine. (I did stop it after a bit, since I'm not interested in the actual result). Might be a RAM issue on either a 32 bits machine or in an old MATLAB version.

Comment: To further on what I said above: the factorial function grow fast, stupendously fast, meaning that you'll probably get more results than you can ever hope to process in your lifetime if you have 30 objects. Why are you permuting those objects? I have a feeling you are falling prey to the [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Adriaan I am using Matlab R2016a trail version. I am working on artifacts reconstruction, where it is possible that the artifacts will brake in to large number of fragments.

Comment: @Adriaan Aside from the computational cost, the returned matrix would require just under 400 million TB of memory for storage.  I 'm not an expert on the use-case here, but there must be another way to proceed further.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have sample constraints for a slightly larger number of components (say, 10 or 11) would you? I've got a recursive solution but I wanted to test it on a different data set before posting it.

Comment: @beaker in my case  number of constraints will increase with number of components, for example Fresco was broken in to 25 pieces. In recursion solution is it possible to get??

Comment: From what i understand, if you have many constraints, then the number of possible sequences might be reasonable. then you might try for a graph approach. Start from a clique (all connections exist between all objects/nodes of the graph) then remove edges according to the constraints. Finally try to come with some graph algorithm. on the sparse graph/ matrix resulting from applying all the constraints....

Comment: @LucieBosch I understand that, but do you have an example of a smaller problem that I can try out? I can make up examples myself, but I don't know how representative they are of your actual problem.

Comment: @beaker I want solution in the from of precedence diagram with all the sequences in the diagram, you can consider the example of the question I posted. or in other words my main aim is to get all feasible sequence given a numbers cultural relics and precedence constraints, I tried to do it by permutation but can't able to do for more then 10 components.

Comment: The reason I asked for a larger example of your constraints is that 1) I need to know how to model the constraints, and 2) I need to know how many actual valid permutations there are. If there are not enough constraints (thus too many permutations) then you won't be able to compute a result. If you want to clarify your question, just hit the [edit] link.

Comment: @beaker well constraints are not too much, I tried to do it for 10 objects and number of valid permutations is 103680, so I think I have to search for different ways , can i use data structures?

Comment: "constraints are not too much" doesn't help me at all. I don't know how to model "not too much". This is why I stopped responding before, because I unless I get some actual data, I can't help you.

Comment: @beaker I put code for six objects in the question with constraints. Does it help you?

Comment: I don't know. Are they representative of your actual constraints? Will you have a constraint such as "4 can come after 5 or 3, but not immediately after 6", or will an element always be valid once it has passed the first constraint? How many valid permutations are there on the largest problem?

Comment: @beaker 4 can come after 5 or 3 means if in a given sequences  5 or 3 is already presented then 4 can be added. (e.g 1 2 3 4 5; 3 2 4 5 1;  5 3 1 2 4; etc). so 4 can come after 6 given that 5 or 3 are already presented in the sequences.   For 10 objects:-  Number of valid permutation is more then 100,000 . I want to use for 30 objects so number of valid permutations may be much higher then 100,000.