# How to remove certain rows in permutation according to constraints?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have following output form permutation:-

```
A= 1 2 4 7 9 10
   1 3 4 9 7 8
   1 2 9 4 7 10
   1 2 4 5 6 8
   1 2 3 5 7 9
   1 2 5 6 7 9
```

I want to remove the rows in which 9 or 5 or both is coming before 7. Final answer should be:-

```
 1 2 4 7 9 10
 1 2 4 5 6 8
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Dear Lucie, reposting the [more-or-less same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242533/is-there-any-way-to-do-permutation-of-more-than-11-components) does not help in getting answers, especially not when your use-case is still not clear. I am still rather unconvinced that your method of approaching the problem at hand is indeed the best method, due to the factorial growth of the possible number of permutations. You'll be better of by finding a different method, since this many permutations will not be calculated before your thesis' deadline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general approach:

```
A = [1 2 4 7 9 10
     1 3 4 9 7 8
     1 2 9 4 7 10
     1 2 4 5 6 8
     1 2 3 5 7 9
     1 2 5 6 7 9]; % data
v = 7; % values "after" 
w = [5 9]; % values "before"
ind = any(ismember(A,v), 2) & any(ismember(A,w), 2); % rows that qualify
[~, indv] = max(ismember(A(ind,:),v), [], 2); % col index of "after" values
[~, indw] = max(ismember(A(ind,:),w), [], 2); % col index of "before" values
remove = indw<indv; % these should be removed, among those given by ind
ind = find(ind); 
A(ind(remove),:) = []; % remove
```

Answer (score 0):

This code with work for any size of A , it checks the index of every column of 7 ,5 and 9 , compares them if 7 is coming before both it stores in y , it also checks if any of the above numbers is not present in the row

```
A= [1 2 4 7 9 10
1 3 4 9 7 8
1 2 9 4 7 10
1 2 4 5 6 8
1 2 3 5 7 9
1 2 5 6 7 9]
[row,col] = size(A);
n = 1;
for i = 1:row
     sev_index = find(A(i,:) == 7);if(isempty(sev_index))sev_index = 0;end
     fiv_index = find(A(i,:) == 5);if(isempty(fiv_index))fiv_index = col + 1;end 
     nine_index = find(A(i,:) == 9);if(isempty(nine_index))nine_index = col + 1;end
     if(sev_index < fiv_index && sev_index < nine_index)
         y(n,:) = A(i,:)
         n = n + 1;
     end
end
```

y

The output is

```
y =

     1     2     4     7     9    10
     1     2     4     5     6     8
```

Comment: why a down vote ? for what ? just because i gave an alternative solution ?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I guess it's because you use a loop that's not necessary, have 4 single line ifs (hard to read and debug). In general, this answer contains code that's considered suboptimal in MATLAB. Upvoting it will further encourage such practice.